# Pandas rolling window must be an int

Tags: python, pandas

this is my data:

```
 data
Out[100]: 
                       SIGNAL  RET in next 1 month
PERMNO  DATE                                      
13977.0 2014-11-30   5.850454            -0.213683
13921.0 2014-11-30   8.730690             0.081111
71271.0 2014-11-30   6.866488             0.015245
13928.0 2014-11-30  13.064670             0.045255
87659.0 2014-11-30  15.503133            -0.011229
                      ...                  ...
17093.0 2018-11-30   5.385037            -0.142579
27334.0 2018-11-30  18.491897            -0.047384
84656.0 2018-11-30  21.838645            -0.182517
82634.0 2018-11-30  37.191351            -0.122751
45751.0 2018-11-30   8.142674            -0.100902
```

where DATE is timestamp. I want to get the sum of 'RET in next month' of 2 sequencial months. I tried this:

```
data.groupby(level='PERMNO')['RET in next 1 month'].rolling('2M').sum()
```

and this:

```
data.groupby(level='PERMNO')['RET in next 1 month'].rolling(2*pd.offsets.MonthEnd()).sum()
```

Both of these raise an error:

```
ValueError: window must be an integer
```

However, I tried the example in offical webpage:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 1, 4]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:07'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:09')])

df.rolling('2s').sum()
Out[99]: 
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:07  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:09  4.0
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Use `df = data.reset_index(level='PERMNO').groupby('PERMNO')['RET in next 1 month'].rolling('30D').sum()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me the differents between these code @jezrael

Comment: Maine difference is `30D`, it is better explained in dupe, also is used DatetimeIndex before this solution.